# Realtime update Firestore with Cloud Functions in development env

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Real-time update is not working with `firebase serve` in my development environment. It's working fine when deployed in production.

```
exports.onApplyCreated = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const data = change.after.data()
        const userId = context.params.userId

        console.log('New apply <${userId}>')
        return "Done."
    });
```

There is no log printed in shell when using `serve` but it works well when logged in production.

Comment: You need to invoke them when running locally as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_firestore_functions).

Comment: @Kato I see, thank you for the link. I hope there will be a way to test it like production in the future.